# Contrasts can be applied to factors with 2 error in lm

Tags: r

I have a data frame with about 40 rows of data and I am trying to run a multiple regression analysis. I am a beginner with R and don't know what's wrong. I have cleaned out the NA's with the omit.na function

```
Regression <- lm(y ~ annu+gdp+pce+int+oil+usex+exf+inxf+m.2, data = data)
```

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]])
> : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels In
> addition: Warning message: In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs
> introduced by coercion

Comment: The error tells you that one of the categorical IVs has only a single level. Since you don't share `data`, it's impossible for us to know which one. You can reproduce the error with e.g. `lm(mpg ~ wt + tmp, transform(mtcars, tmp = factor(1)))`.

Comment: Seconding Maurits's point - try `sapply(data, \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) )` and see which of your variables have only 1 unique value.